# how to make the result appear in popup widow?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to make the result comes out in a popup window.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234","fyp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT password FROM admin WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND Admin = '$_POST[admin]'");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))



 echo "your password is : " . " $row['password']" ;


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Is it possible to make it echoed in popup window like javascript alert messages ??

I have tried this but still not working

```
echo "<script> alert ("<?php echo 'your password is:  ' . '$row['password']'?>")</script>";
```

Comment: Before you continue with your project, you may want to fix some of the underlying issues with this code. For example, your script is prone to SQL injection and you shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: php knows nothing about the web page. If your code is called via an ajax call then you could possibly use javascript, on the web page, to display the result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a maybe strange solution for this a while back.

```
echo "<style onload=\"jsfunc($row['password']);\"></style>";

//in your html or javascript add this function
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function jsfunc(data){
        alert(data);
    }
</script>
```

the style tag is invisible and will run the function onload, so when its gets echoed. Also I use the style tag because its one of the few tags where the onload works when you echo it like this.
 
Its a strange solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are some serious flaws in your code, including it being open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I'd recommend changing it to look more like this:

```
$con = new MySQLi("localhost","root","1234","fyp");
if($con->connect_errorno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".$sql->connect_error;
}

$email = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$admin = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['admin']);

$query = "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE email = '$email' AND Admin = '$admin'";
$result = $sql->query($query);

if($result) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $pass = $row['password'];
    echo '<script> alert("Your password is '.$pass.'");</script>';
} else {
    //do some error handling
}

//the closing of a mysqli connection is not required but
mysqli_close($con);
```

Real escape string is not 100% proof against injection but is a good place to start with sanitising your inputs. Additionally I would strongly advise against storing your passwords in plain text. Please take a look at the PHP `sha1()` function or the SQL equivalent when storing the passwords initially.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you get a console error suggesting it's a JS error? Is the alert message blank? Have you got `ini_set("display_errors", 1)` on in your PHP and, if so, does it have any errors in the server side code?

Answer (score -2):

Use this code

```
<?php 
$alert='your password is:  '.$row['password'];
?>
<script>
alert("<?php echo $alert; ?>");
</script>
```

It will work for sure.

Comment: You need to remove the single quotes from around the outside of the `$row` variable.

Comment: Sorry. That's right. Just copied that statement from the question. ;)